# Properly stop a service when the binding activity is killed by recent apps

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding, android-recents, screen-off

I have a bound service playing sounds with `Soundpool`. It works normally if the app exits normally (using back button).

However, when the app is killed by the recent app, in the next run, the service (sound) behaves abnormally, especially, when the screen is OFF.

In detail:

1. When the app starts after being killed by the recent app, I still can play the sound normally when the screen is ON.
2. When the screen is OFF, the sound plays OK in next few seconds and then start to flicker. However, the symptom disappears when the screen turned back on.

I tested with Android N. And the code is nothing special, just like this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) from Android developer website.

I don't know what is the differences between normal exit and app killed by recent apps.

How to properly stop the [bound service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) if the app is removed from recent apps. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _'service that binds to an activity'_? There is no way to "bind to an `Activity`. Please explain how these components are bound together.

Comment: I mean the bound service https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: Describe what you mean by "behaves abnormally". What do you expect to happen and what actually happens (or doesn't happen). We aren't mind readers here.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question, hopefully, it is easier to understand.

Comment: You write _"the code is nothing special, just like this link from Android developer website"_. However, the linked article includes nothing about bound `Services`. Please post the code from your `onBind()` and `onUnbind()` methods and any other relevant methods.

Answer (score 0):

Killing from recent apps may be the same as force stop on some devices so no `onPause` or `onStop` is called on the activity in this case, so the service is probably not being unbound correctly.

If your service is not bound to a running activity and doesn't run in the foreground, the system may stop it at any time.